# Where are the files downloaded through custom script extension stored in virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have one script and one bin file and through the script file I want to execute the bin file. This is giving error. I would like to know where are these files stored in virtual machine after running custom script extension and where can I see the logs of this?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#troubleshoot-and-support, regarding where these files are stored:

> The specified files are downloaded into the following folder on the
> target virtual machine.
>
> `C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.*\Downloads\<n>`
>
> where <n> is a decimal integer, which may change between executions of
> the extension. The 1.* value matches the actual, current
> typeHandlerVersion value of the extension. For example, the actual
> directory could be
>
> `C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.8\Downloads\2`

Answer (score 0):

check it in `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\`

more information: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#troubleshoot-and-support